# Changing Router configuration to give same IP subnet as on its WAN [pfsense]

Tags: router, pfsense, subnet

My currrent configuration is

```
 Modem-->Pfsense[WAN(10.1.1.4) + LAN(192.168.1.1)] -->[WAN]Router[LANs]--->PC1
```

Now the problem was that the router gave its own IP to computer like

192.168.2.10  with gateway  192.168.2.1

The internet was working but pfsense was showing it as only one IP which was cooming to router even though there were 3 computers connected through router.Router was acting as DHCP server.

Then i searched on internet that i have to put cable from

```
PFsense LAN to Router LAN not its WAN
```

and wow it worked i don't know why but it worked.All ips are now in pfSESNE and i can view their downloads.

I want to know is it the best method because my WAN port on Router is empty and now i can't access the home page of router. Initially i used to type the gateway but what should i do now

2) Do i need to make one of computer[`server with AD` installed] as `DHCP server` or `PFsense` is fine working as DHCP server. I want to know which method is used in enterprises so that i can try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have two routers in your setup? It's likely that the second one isn't necessary, as pfsense is your main router. Your ideal setup should look something like:

```
Modem->[(wan) PFsense (lan)]->[LAN Switch]->PC1
```

I suspect that the second router is actually a wireless access point. If that's the case, then yes, you should connect the a LAN port from that AP to your LAN switch. Also, make sure to turn off DHCP on the wireless AP, as you don't want two DHCP servers on your network.

Adding more info following your edit...

It doesn't really matter whether you host DHCP on your pfsense router or on your AD server. Either will handle the task just fine. If you host it the windows server, you get the advantage of having the hostnames of DHCP leases registered in DNS. In a small environment, that's probably not a big deal, though. Just be sure to only have one DHCP server on your network.

Comment: Actually i have to use router for wireless clients. Is there any way to access Router Homepage if i want to chnage wifi password

Comment: It would be less confusing for yourself and others if you didn't call it a "router", as it's not actually routing anything in this case. Anyway, disconnect the AP from the rest of the network, and connect a PC to it. If you don't know what IP it's supposed to have, use the factory reset pin to reset it. You should then get an IP from it via DHCP. Then pull up the management page in your browser, set its IP to something in the subnet of the rest of your LAN, disable DHCP, and then reconnect the LAN port to the rest of your network.